# Does $L_1$ convergence of continuous functions imply pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $C[0,1]$ which is convergent with respect to the $L_1$ norm.  Then is $(f_n(x))$ necessarily convergent for all $x\in[0,1]$?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I'm not aware of a counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x) = (-1)^n x^n.$ Then $f_n\in C[0,1],$ and $f_n \to 0$ in $L^1,$ but $f_n(1)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 4):

The "dancing indicators" counterexample:
$$\chi_{[0, 1/2]}, \chi_{[1/2, 1]}, \chi_{[0, 1/3]}, \chi_{[1/3, 2/3]}, \chi_{[2/3, 1]}, \chi_{[0, 1/4]}, \chi_{[1/4, 2/4]}, \ldots$$

Edit: as noted in the comments, these functions are not continuous. However, if you replace the indicators with continuous ["tent" functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) supported on the same interval, you obtain the same contradiction. I like this type of counterexample more than the one given by zhw since you can use it to construct a sequence that fails to converges pointwise for all $x \in [0,1]$, rather than one that fails to converge pointwise at a single $x$.

Comment: well, those are not continuous

Comment: If you modify the indicators to be "trapezoidal", having a linear ramp to the peak value, this example fails to converge pointwise at any point in the interval