# Showing that $||f_n||_1 \to 0.$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Here is the function I have $f_n(x) := (-1)^n(x + 1) \sin (nx + 1)$ for $x \in [0,1], n \in \mathbb N.$

Here is my trial for showing that $||f_n||_1 \to 0:$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (x + 1) |\sin (nx + 1)| dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x |\sin (nx + 1)| dx + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} |\sin (nx + 1)| dx$

But $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} |\sin (nx + 1)| dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \sin (nx + 1) dx + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} -\sin (nx + 1) dx  = 0$

And in the second integration, I used integration by parts where I took the following choices: $$ u = x, \quad \quad  dv = \sin (nx + 1) dx$$
And $$du = dx, \quad \quad v= \int dv = \int \sin (nx + 1) dx =0 $$

Hence,   $\int_{0}^{1} x |\sin (nx + 1)| dx = 0$ as well. And the required is proved.

Am I correct in the above reasoning why the norm goes to zero?

**EDIT:**

The original question was "Construct a sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C_{c}[0,1]$ such that $(c)||{f_n}||_{1} \to 0$ and $f_n(x)$ does not converge for any $x$." the example I wrote in the question was an example of a solution to this question given to me by one of my colleagues (just a trial for a solution).

Comment: By the definition of the absolute value, oh maybe I am wrong then, I do not know.@BrianMoehring

Comment: By the way, the limit you're trying to show isn't even true.  One may show, with a little bit of work, that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \|f_n\|_1 \geq \frac2\pi$.  Did you perhaps change the problem from its original form?  And if not, what is the source?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I guess the original problem was about the integral and then Riemann-Lebesgue lemma can be applied after little trigonometry.

Comment: To clarify a little from @RyszardSzwarc's comment and also update my previous comment, showing $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \to 0$ follows by Riemann-Lebesgue, but $\|f_n\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\,dx \to 3/\pi \neq 0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring the original question was "Construct a sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C_{c}[0,1]$ such that $(c)$ $$||{f_n}||_{1} \to 0 and $f_n(x)$ does not converge for any $x$." the example I wrote in the question was an example of the solution to this question given to me.

Comment: Your colleague is mistaken then.  As I said, $\|f_n\|_1 \to 3/\pi$ for your sequence.  For the actual problem, consider for instance, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085400)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you very very much for the link! .... I did not get though why ||.||_1 tends to zero in the first answer in the link you gave ..... could you please post it as an answer here (off course if this is sth you like to do)

Comment: @BrianMoehring also, I had another question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524271/constructing-a-sequence-f-n-subset-c-c0-1-such-that?noredirect=1#comment9505654_4524271 in case you would like to take a look

Comment: My link was to angryavian's answer, not the "top answer" by zhw, which doesn't satisfy your conditions, because zhw's sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ for every $x \in [0,1)$.  If you're still interested in zhw's answer for some other reason, note that $\|f_n\|_1 =  \int_0^1 x^n\,dx = \frac1{n+1} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.