# A more succinct way of showing that $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ does not converge for any $x \in [0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

Here is the proof I have:

> [image]
> [image]

Is there a more succinct (elegant and organized) way of showing that $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ does not converge for any $x \in [0,1]$?

Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Please give a reference for the text or article from which your quoted proof comes.

Comment: @coffeemath it was a solution given to me by one of my colleagues (just a trial)

Comment: Why treat $x \in [0,1] \setminus \{\pi/2\}$ ? I ask because $\pi/2 \approx 1.57$ is not in $[0,1]$ in the first place.

Comment: @coffeemath ok I see :)

Comment: @coffeemath I think I will delete my question since it seems like my colleague's answer is incorrect I guess ......... The original question was "Construct a sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C_{c}[0,1]$ such that $(c)||{f_n}||_{1} \to 0$ and $f_n(x)$ does not converge for any $x$." the example I wrote in the question was an example of a solution to this question given to me by one of my colleagues (just a trial for a solution).

Comment: If you decide to delete, in my opinion a good thing to post would be the original question of the comment you just made, maybe with the conditions spelled out like what the || * ||_1 means and also C_[0,1] [is this last continuous compact support? but [0,1] already compact.[

Comment: The example of your colleague does not satisfy $\|f_n\|_1\to 0$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524448/showing-that-f-n-1-to-0#comment9505814_4524448

Answer (score 0):

Fix an $x\in(0,1]$, for each $m\in \Bbb N$ choose the smallest $n$ such that

$$nx+1-m\pi=a≥0.$$

Since $x\in(0,1]$, it is obvious that $a<1$. Using the fact $\sin(x-\pi)=-\sin x$, we have

$$|\sin (nx+1)|=|\sin a|<\sin 1.$$

Thus there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|f_n(x)|<(x+1)\sin 1$ and therefore if the sequence converges, it would converge to some number with absolute value at most $(x+1)\sin 1.$

But applying the same strategy also shows that there are also infinitely many $n$ such that $|f_n(x)|>(x+1)\sin (\pi/2-1)$ consequently, the sequence does not converge.